# Can't install pillow module

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have been working on a small rpg game by using python. I want a picture to pop up during the last boss and I have been told that is possible by using `pillow`. While trying to install it via this code:

```
pip install pillow
```

I get an error that states:

```
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

What am I supposed to do?

Comment: You don't have `pip` installed, so just install `pip`. Alternatively, you may have it installed, but the location of it might not be on the PATH.

Comment: Would you mind explaining how I install it correctly?

Comment: If you don't have `pip`, you can just get it from python.org I believe. If you have it but it's not on the PATH, search for how to add directories to the PATH environmental variable on the operating system you're using.

Comment: Since you're using Windows, I suggest you download a pre-built copy of the module from Christoph Gohlke's website the [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) — then afterwards all you'll have to do is install it.

Comment: Please check my answer, does it solve your problem..?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the `pip` script by Python is not found by Windows. The reasons may be:

- Improper installation of Python (leading to the file not being on your device)
- `PATH` variable not set properly (leading to the inability of Windows to recognize `pip`, even if it is present on your device)

Verify if the script is present in your Python installation folder. The default path for `pip` and other scripts is **`C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\<version>\Scripts`**

- If there is a `pip.exe` file in that, just add the full path of the Scripts folder to the Windows `PATH` variable. Check out [this link](https://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-10/add-windows-path-environment-variable/) if you need help with setting the `PATH` variable
- If the file is absent, I recommend a **clean re-install** of Python on your PC (just to ensure all files are present)